# java Manipulating a string (inserting a letter in front of every character after a space)

Tags: java, regex, string

if I have a string which looks something like `string="1 3 5 8 15"` and I want to manipulate that string such a way that in front of every non space character (which will always be a number) I insert a letter for example `D` and the new string will become `string ="D1 D3 D5 D8 D15"`. In my particular code, the initial string is inputed by the user if thats of any relevance, and the string characters are always single or double digits.

Comment: Please include your relevant code and have a look here about how to ask questions [ask]

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
str.replaceAll("^| ", "$0D");
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it.

```
String [] arr = str.split(" "); //split on white space
String builder = "";
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     builder += "D" + arr[i];
     if(i!=arr.length-1){
         builder += " ";
     }
}
```

Of course, there's many many ways, since strings have been studied in and out. My method splits on whitespace, and rebuilds a string inserting "D" in front of every element.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all numbers (\d+):

```
string.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "D$1");
```

Edit: you can also limit the size of the numbers to 2, with

\d{1,2}

Comment: what does \\d+ mean? the first parameter is the replace part right and the second is the replace with.

Comment: @j.doe `\d` means "number", but we have to escape the `\ ` here - therefore `\\d`. And then we want to capture as many of those as possible, therefore `\\d+`

Comment: \d matches a single digit from 0 to 9. The + makes it so that this happens from 1 to infinite times, as many times as possible. the javadocs for replaceall: "public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
"